# как лучше всего в linux ограничить пропускную способность на конкретном порту на входящий трафик для каждого айпи?

Tags: linux, firewall

У меня debian 9, и есть публичный сервер, который работает на порту 3000.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы клиенты, которые подключаются к этому серверу, не могли слать трафик быстрее 200кб/c. Но при этом чтобы сервер клиентам мог отправлять трафик без ограничений.

Лимит на каждого клиента отдельный, т.е. два клиента могут вместе сделать трафик 400кб/с, но по отдельности только максимум 200кб/c.

Ну и важно, чтобы этот лимит работал только на порту 3000.

Как мне подойти к этой задаче? Какие посоветуете инструменты?

Comment: Если это хттп, то используй nginx

Comment: нет, это свой прокол

Comment: Смотреть надо в сторону tc. Но там две проблемы: во-первых, входящий трафик вообще плохо шейпится по очевидным причинам. Во-вторых, вроде бы у tc нет qdisc'а, который бы распределял указанные параметры для каждого IP (просто потому что qdisc'и не особо заморачиваются понятием IP)

Comment: Там все есть, но надо голову сломать как это работает. По моему лучше не шейпить, а поставить fc_codel на интерфейс в ингресс. Там что-то вроде "честного" распределения пропускной способности - всем клиентам поровну.

Comment: Ipt queue ещё посмотри

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук tcp или udp?

Comment: @eri протокол tcp

Comment: На tcp есть ask и скорости можно регулировать просто читая сокет медленнее на уровне приложения

Comment: Ограничить **входящий** трафик технически невозможно: компьютер не в состоянии быть властелином мира и контролировать, кто чего и сколько хочет ему прислать, он узнаёт о входящем трафике лишь постфактум, когда он уже пришёл. Можно выкидывать «лишние» пришедшие пакеты тем же шейпером, но это будет лишь видимость ограничения скорости, а клиент всё равно сможет перегрузить сетевой интерфейс и устроить DoS-атаку, если захочет.

Comment: @andreymal да ставишь ifb на маршрут и трафик становится исходящим. Но в новых ядрах есть ингресс очереди и ifb теперь не нужен.

Comment: от ддоса это не поможет - согласен, но как сайд эффект уменьшает окно tcp и скорость падает

Answer (score 3):

Всетаки рекомендую работать с ограничением на уровне приложения. Если его модифицировать сложно, то поставьте перед ним прокси. Хороший и готовый к бою NGINX.

Сервер для tcp определяется директивой stream, а ограничить скорость легко директивой proxy_upload_rate, которая работает в этом контексте. 
 https://nginx.org/ru/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_upload_rate

Ограничение скорости средствами iptables или tc возможно только через отбрасывание уже полученных пакетов или набивание очередей, с отбрасываением того что в очередь не поместилось. Конечно tcp поймет что скорости не хватает и будет писать медленнее, но будет много повторов отправки что можт сказаться на производительности сети.